# Force POST form submission to send cookies

Tags: forms, post, iframe, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a feature for a Chrome extension which requires making a same-origin POST request to an endpoint. For brevity, I'll leave out the particular details of the website. This request creates a resource of a given kind. I've succeeded in being able to create many kinds of these resources, but there's one type in particular that always fails.

When you use the website's own UI to create this kind of resource, I noticed that the resulting POST request is sent with the `cookie` header, along with some other stuff that looks unfamiliar to me. Here's an excerpt of the request headers:

```
:authority:www.example.com
:method:POST
:path:/path/to/endpoint
:scheme:https
[...]
cookie: [...]
```

The cookies are *not* sent for any other resource type, just this one.

Now, since this passes along cookies, the website's own javascript can't be using ajax. In fact, the site is posting to an `<iframe>` by linking a `<form>` to an `<iframe>` of a particular name.

So, I modified my Chrome extension code to use forms to post to iframes instead of making an ajax request, just like it's done natively on the website. However, the resulting POST requests still do not pass cookies. I have found nothing unique about the parts of the website's UI which create these special resources which might cause the requests to pass cookies.

How does Chrome decide when to pass cookies in a web request? How can I force it to do this for a `<form>` submission?

---

EDIT: Here are some more details, as requested.

To create a resource, just POST multipart data to `/resource-endpoint`. In jQuery you might do something like

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('property', 'value'); // Add payload values

$.ajax({
  url: '/resource-endpoint'
  type: 'POST',
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  data: data
});
```

Doing it this way will create most resources, except for the "special" resource. Since AJAX requests cannot pass along cookies, and the request to create the "special" resource must include cookies, I have to mimic the website's UI more closely.

```
var id = 'some-id';
var iframe = $('<iframe name="' + id + '"></iframe>');
$(document.body).append(iframe);

var form = $('<form></form>');

form.attr({
  target: id,
  action: '/resource-endpoint,
  method: 'POST',
  enctype: 'multipart/form-data'
});

// Add payload values
form.append('<input name="property" value="value" />');

$(document.body).append(form);

form.submit();
```

This still sends along requests, but there appears to be something missing, because requests to create the "special" resource do not include cookies. I'm not sure how the native website javascript is doing this, as I can't find any difference between the forms that create regular resources and the form that creates "special" resources.

---

EDIT: Nevermind, I saw a native "special resource" POST request from the UI which doesn't pass along these cookies, so the secret must not be the cookies.

Comment: I get what you are aiming for and all, just a few questions though (and some requests), not entirely familiar with how chrome extensions work yet, but I think it would be a lot of help to the community to provide a little bit more info. Will it be alright for you to post some code snippets on how you are *creating this kind of resource* or something like that?

Comment: Added more details, thanks for the feedback :)